# How to match all items don't start with 'abc' in a comma-separated text, with regex?

Tags: regex

I have a text like:

abc13v,bc23c,8uend,abcabc,oabci,

(There is also a comma following the last item)

The regex (which I ask for) will return the matches:

bc23c
8uend
oabci

How can I write the regex?

Thanks

Comment: Which language are you using? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

`^(?!^abc)(\w+)$`

Using a negative lookahead, we can state that it shouldn't match `abc` at the start of the line: `(?!^abc)`

To capture the leftovers, we use the capture group `(\w+)` to grab everything from a-z both upper and lowercase and the digits 0-9 one or more times.

To make sure it's handling the entire line the extra `^` defines "From the start" and `$` defines "To the end"

See it working [on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WAFUZW/1)

If you're using C#, Java or a similar language that requires more escape characters, use this one:

`^(?!^abc)(\\w+)$`